# How to automatically trigger reindexing between SVN & Opengrok

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn, opengrok

We are planning to use Opengrok in our Project. With the help of the below url:
http://algopadawan.blogspot.com/2012/07/installing-opengrok-on-windows.html

I did a small poc in my local desktop and I was able to get opengrok application up.
As part of poc did a manual indexing as mentioned in the above url.

In our project we use SVN as version control and any commit made in svn would like to get it indexed automatically in Opengrok instead of manual indexing.
Can anyone let me know how we can achieve this ?

Many Thanks,
Sachin

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

1. Modify the post-commit hook of your svn repository to fire off the reindexing of the repository, you could use a shell script to accomplish this.
2. Create a cron job to fire off the indexing at a certain time interval, using a similar shell script or script of your choice.